# Capturing data AND image with php, saving data in a new directory named dynamically based upon filename

Tags: php, filesystems

I am a bit inexperienced with PHP so I would appreciate any help I can get. I am looking to:

Capture user's first name, last name, and an image. After they have put these bits of data inside the form, it will be sent to the php processor which uses the users lastname as as a variable, setting it as a new directory containing a data.txt and avatar.jpg || .png || .bmp || .gif (which should hold all of the info as entered into the web form). Security is not an issue in this, nor is validation as I have that part covered. I simply need to know how I could approach this. Here is some sample code which is currently getting me no-where:

index.html:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="process.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="512000" />
<input type="text" name="fname">
Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
```

process.php

```
<?php

    $uploaddir = '/home/nicholasabrams/public_html/' + $_POST['lname'] + '/'
                +  $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

    echo "<p>";


    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
      echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    } else {
       echo "Upload failed";
    }

    echo "</p>";
    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
    print_r($_FILES);
    print "</pre>";
```

Comment: Just as a pointer to why this is **SO** bad an idea... What happens when 2 `John Smith` join. **BANG** Whoever joins last destroys the one that joined first.

Comment: Yes, that's a good question. Another things: you have to create the directory if it not exists, and, what happens if the last name have special chars?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that last names are unique , you can do it many ways so I'll leave that with you here is how can you do the rest

```
<?php
//process.php
$uploaddir = '/home/nicholasabrams/public_html/' + $_POST['lname'].'/';
//TODO get the extension of a file from $_FILES['userfile']['name']
//$EXTENSION=.....
$EXTENSION = 'jpg';  
if( ! is_dir($uploaddir) ){
  mkdir($uploaddir);
}else{
// CONFLICT differen user same last name , or same user needs to change some data
}
 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir.'avatar.'.$EXTENSION ){
   $data = "Last Name:" . $_POST['lname'] ."\n";
   //$data .= ..... additional data that you need
   file_put_contents($uploaddir.'data.txt',$data);

}
```

Comment: As already mentioned , this should be used in controlled environment, ie user can upload PHP file and execute it via Web Browser , you will need to check additionally if this is actually and image file before saving it.